# Apply Filter on last function pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with values :

```
id, time,   boolean
1   ,4/12/21 11:36, 0
1   ,4/13/21 11:36, 0
1   ,4/14/21 11:36, 1
1   ,4/15/21 11:36, 1
1   ,4/16/21 11:36, 0
1   ,4/17/21 11:36, 0
1   ,4/18/21 11:36, 1
1   ,4/19/21 11:36, 0
```

My desired output is:

```
id, time,   boolean ,new_time
1   ,4/12/21 11:36, 0, null
1   ,4/13/21 11:36, 0,  null
1   ,4/14/21 11:36, 1,  4/14/21 11:36
1   ,4/15/21 11:36, 1,  4/15/21 11:36
1   ,4/16/21 11:36, 0,  4/15/21 11:36
1   ,4/17/21 11:36, 0,  4/15/21 11:36
1   ,4/18/21 11:36, 1,  4/18/21 11:36
1   ,4/19/21 11:36, 0,  4/18/21 11:36
```

Out put includes a new column which will have value on condition:
a) If boolean is 0, populate last time when boolean was 1.

I have reached a a stage where I am able to filter the records. but I am not sure on how to add filter on last condition.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time')
df=df.withColumn("new_time",when(df.boolean == 0,last("time",True).over(w)).otherwise(lit(None)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `when` inside `last`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'new_time', 
    F.last(
        F.when(F.col('boolean') == 1, F.col('time')), 
        True
    ).over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time'))
)

df2.show()
+---+-------------+-------+-------------+
| id|         time|boolean|     new_time|
+---+-------------+-------+-------------+
|  1|4/12/21 11:36|      0|         null|
|  1|4/13/21 11:36|      0|         null|
|  1|4/14/21 11:36|      1|4/14/21 11:36|
|  1|4/15/21 11:36|      1|4/15/21 11:36|
|  1|4/16/21 11:36|      0|4/15/21 11:36|
|  1|4/17/21 11:36|      0|4/15/21 11:36|
|  1|4/18/21 11:36|      1|4/18/21 11:36|
|  1|4/19/21 11:36|      0|4/18/21 11:36|
+---+-------------+-------+-------------+
```